# Add css background image in node.js using express

Tags: css, node.js, express

I am experimenting with Node.js and am a complete new bee.. Haven't been able to find an answer.  My directory structure is

app --> public --> a.jpg & style.css

I provide access to these files in express as follows:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var PORT = 3000;
app.use(express.static("./app/public"));
```

The css works, but when i call the background-image property in the style sheet it is unable to find the image and apply it. I have tried the following combinations with no luck:

```
body{
    background-image: "../app/public/a.jpg";
    background-image: "./app/public/a.jpg";
    background-image: "/app/public/a.jpg";
    background-image: "/public/a.jpg";
    background-image: "./public/a.jpg";
    background-image: "/a.jpg";
    background-image: "a.jpg";
}
```

can someone point me in the right direction.

Comment: Usually backgrounds need sizes or at least content that will stretch the tag with the background applied to. Do you have any content in the body tag?

Comment: Try this `./a.jpg`. Will take you to `public` and from there to `a.jpg`

Comment: thanks just tried it but still no go :-/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The path to your image should be set inside `url("...")`.

Based on your project structure, it would be:

```
body{
    background-image: url("a.jpg");
}
```

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image)

Comment: wow.. lol i can't believe i missed that.. thank you so much. it works now